# Have a JSP tag inside a Jar instead of WEB-INF/tags

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, jsp-tags

Is it possible to have **tag files** (sample.tag) **inside a jar archive** instead of the WEB-INF of the .war archive?

I want to re-use a tag file in multiple web-apps without having to copy it into the WEB-INF always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes tag files can be [packaged](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPTags6.html#wp90271) in a [JAR](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPTags5.html) file.

> Summary: Tag files can be placed in one of two locations: in the
>   /WEB-INF/tags/ directory or subdirectory of a web application or in a
>   JAR file (see Packaged Tag Files) in the /WEB-INF/lib/ directory of a
>   web application.